# Construct such $d$ that $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}, d)$ is complete metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Good evening!

I had topology exam yesterday and I had a question that gave me problems.
Lets consider $\mathrm{G} = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z} $ , i.e. real line without the integers, where $\rho$ is natural metric on $\mathrm{G}$. Find metric $d$ equivalent to
$\rho$, where $(\mathrm{G},d)$ is complete metric space.

---

It is obvious that $(\mathrm{G},\rho)$ is not complete, but I don't know how to construct $d$. Can I do something like get rid of Cauchy's property only in integral points of real line and maintain in the other ones?

Comment: You want to look at the reals without the integers in such a way that numbers on each side of an integer that are close to each other in the usual sense are very, very far away from each other in a new metric. Just look at the graph of $1/\sin(\pi x)$. Topologically this graph is the reals without the integers, and giving it the induced metric from $\mathbf R^2$ any Cauchy sequence has to lie in just one of the branches of the graph (well, all but finitely many terms in a Cauchy sequence lie in the same branch).

Comment: $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases} \min(|\cot\pi x-\cot\pi y|,1) & \text{if }\exists n\in\Bbb{Z} : x,y\in(n,n+1)\\ 1&\text{otherwise} \end{cases} ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space and $A \subset X$, then $A$ can be given a complete metric iff $A$ is a $G_\delta$ subset of $X$, i.e. $A = \cap_{n} U_n$ where all $U_n$ are open in $X$. This is a classical result, and looking at the proof of that result, we also get the complete (and equivalent to $d \restriction A$ on $A$) metric $d_A$ on $A$ defined by:

$$d_A(x,y) = d(x,y) + \sum_{n} \frac{1}{2^n} \left|\frac{1}{d(x,X\setminus U_n)} - \frac{1}{d(y, X\setminus U_n)}\right| $$

This works because the map $x \rightarrow (x, \frac{1}{d(x, X\setminus U_0)},  \frac{1}{d(x, X\setminus U_1)},\ldots)$ embeds $A$ as a closed subset into $X \times \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, which has a complete metric from the sum, as described. See [these notes](http://artsci.kyushu-u.ac.jp/~ssaito/eng/maths/Gdelta.pdf) for a proof for this, and also why being a $G_\delta$ is necessary.

Note that we can apply this to $U_n = X \setminus \{n, -n\}$ to get $\cap_n U_n = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 5):

This is same as construct a metric on (0,1) that is compatible.

To do so, you just need to notice (0,1) is homeomorphic to the real line R. Now pull back the standard metric on R to (0,1), which gives you an "equivalent" but now complete metric.

Such a map is not so hard to get and I bet you have already seen one in the lectures.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Find a closed set $X\subseteq{\bf R}^2$ which is homeomorphic to ${\bf R}\setminus {\bf Z}$. It might be a little easier (easier to write the homeomorphism explicitly, at least) if you look at ${\bf R}\setminus (\pi{\bf Z})$ instead. Then use the fact that a closed subset of a complete metric space is a complete metric space with the subspace metric.