# Sets admissing metrics which make them complete having the same subspace topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I am thinking on the following exercise:

> Show that the following subspaces admit a metric (inducing the
> subspace topology), with respect to which they are complete.
>
> (a) $X=\mathbb{R} \backslash\{0\}$, 
> (b) $Y=\mathbb{R} \backslash
>  \mathbb{Z}$, 
> (c) $Z=\mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash A$ where $A$ is a closed
> set.

I know that the discrete metric space is always complete and hence setting the metric for $X$ to be the discrete metric gives a complete space. But the discrete metric space does not give same subspace topology as induced on $X$ by $\mathbb{R}$. It would be great if someone provides a hint or a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $(c)$ encompasses $(a)$ and $(b)$ as well.

Comment: [Inspiration](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/685550/4280)...

Comment: Thanks. I got that @HennoBrandsma. I just quoted the whole question as it is. Also, thanks for the link. I would appreciate any help on the general part (part c, that is).

Comment: See my answer to that question. An open set is a $G_\delta$ after all..

Comment: So $d'(x,y)=|x-y| + | \frac{1}{d(x,A)} - \frac{1}{d(y,A)}|$ will do.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that @HennoBrandsma. Thank you for the help! I assume $d(x,A) = \inf_{z\in A} d(x,z)$?

Comment: Yes, as usual, it's always non-zero outside $A$ if $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metric $$d'(x,y)= |x-y| + \left|\frac{1}{d(x,A)} - \frac{1}{d(y,A)}\right|$$ on $(X,d)$ with $A \subseteq X$ closed will work. As usual $d(p,A)= \inf\{d(p,a): a \in A\}$ and if $(X,d)$ is complete, so is $(X\setminus A, d')$ and the topology induced by $d'$ is the same as the subspace topology from $d$.

This encompasses all three cases.